# Рассылка на Телеграмм с сайта

Tags: php, telegram

На сайте есть пользователи с номерами телефонов, у многих есть Телеграмм аккаунты. Нужно сделать так, чтобы админ мог отправить сразу всем (у кого есть телеграмм аккаунт) сообщение на Телеграмм.

Например, в админке есть форма для рассылки, админ заполняет текстовое поле и нажимает на волшебную кнопочку `ОТПРАВИТЬ`, и это сообщение "идёт" всем у кого есть ТГ.

В какую сторону копать, что читать? В интернете нашел кучу материалов только на тему как создать бота, но про рассылку ничего не говорится.

Comment: Имеются телеграм клиенты для разных языков, через них вы можете попробовать отправить сообщения на номера телефонов пользователей. Вот она из подобных, может получится
[php-telegram-cli](https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client)

Comment: @MilkiweedGtlt Библиотека по ссылке мёртвая.

Answer (score 2):

Для рассылки сообщений через бота, пользователи должны будут написать вашему боту (подписаться на бота).

Если слать одинаковые сообщения без бота на более чем 40, 50, ну максимум наверное 100 аккаунтов - вас автоматически забанят за спам.
Придется использовать прокси, множество аккаунтов, уникализировать текст

Answer (score 0):

На PHP существует библиотека [danog/madelineproto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto).

```
$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API();
$MadelineProto->phone_login(readline('Enter your phone number: '));
$MadelineProto->complete_phone_login(readline('Enter the code you received: '));
$MadelineProto->messages->sendMessage(['peer' => '@danogentili', 'message' => 'lel'], ['noResponse' => true]);
```

Документации тоже немного, но побольше чем на официальных ресурсах телеграма. Автор русский, на нормальные вопросы даже отвечает в телеграме.

Одной секунды между отправками сообщения может быть слишком мало. Необходимую длительность задержек вам придётся угадывать.